# New drive claims to be the active partition but not the boot partition. Should I change it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I installed a new hard drive (F: in the picture below). My C: drive is the boot drive and the location where Windows is installed. I'm confused why the new drive is marked as active. I'm hesitating to change it since a) that's how it autoconfigured and b) every web page that Google shows me says not to change active settings unless you're sure what you're doing. I'm not sure. So I'm asking. Active is supposed to mean the boot partition, but notice that "Boot" is a separate attribute.

[image]

I haven't rebooted the machine yet in case this is something I should fix first.

Windows 7.

Comment: "Should I change it?" - No; You should leave it alone.  If it needed to be a boot partition it would already be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO your PC is booting from the "System Reserved" Partition on bottom of your table which is "Active", "Primary" and "System". As long as you do not touch that partition attributes you can leave the others unchanged.

Just in case something fails you can boot from an install DVD or USB-Stick and repair/set the active attribute from any physical or logical disk.